how to activate a dbus daemon service located on my user .local?
I was following this answer but I couldn't make my dbus service work, here my dbus service
~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/conf.behavior.lid.service

[D-BUS Service]
Name=conf.behavior.lid.service
# For direct (non-systemd) start; required but may be /bin/false to require systemd
Exec=/home/[my_user]/.local/bin/lid-behavior-conf.sh


but when I run:
gdbus call --session \
    --dest org.freedesktop.DBus \
    --object-path /org/freedesktop/DBus \
    --method org.freedesktop.DBus.StartServiceByName conf.behavior.lid 1

I get:
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:
  The name is not activatable


The correctly command is: gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.DBus --object-path /org/freedesktop/DBus --method org.freedesktop.DBus.StartServiceByName 'conf.behavior.lid.service' '1'

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
